# Jssor slider lazyloading not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I have been looking to optimize my jssor slider for a couples days and I dont seem to be able to make the lazing loading work.

Basicaclly, i'm trying to reduce the initial bandwidth require to download my webpage by making the slider download and show the slides as they appear. 
I tried using the $LazyLoding: 0 option and replaced all "src" attributes of my images to "src2" but the initial bandwidth to download my webpage is not changing.

Here my config:

```
{  
    $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
    $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $HWA: false,
    $LazyLoading: 0,

    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
        $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
    },
    $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
        $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
        $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
        $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
        $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
        $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
    },
    $CaptionSliderOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,
        $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,
        $PlayInMode: 3,
        $PlayOutMode: 3
    }
```

and heres a slide in html

```
<div debug-id="slide-0" style="width: 2160px; height: 1440px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;">
<img u="image" src2="http://foobar.com/foo.jpg" border="0" style="width: 2160px; height: 1440px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;">
<div u="caption" t="LT" id="foo bar" style="position: absolute; line-height: 60px; top: 10px; left: 10px; height: 60px; width: 25%; opacity: 1; background-color: rgb(140, 0, 26);" class="captionRed">
        foooooo                       </div>
<div id="link_bar" u="caption" t="LT" style="position: absolute; top: 1375px; line-height: 60px; left: 1800px; height: 60px; width: 350px; opacity: 1;" class="captionLinksRed">
    barrrr
</div>
<div u="caption" t="LT" id="link_foo" style="position: absolute; top: 1375px; line-height: 60px; left: 1400px; height: 60px; width: 350px; opacity: 1;" class="captionLinksRed">
    foo bar 
</div>
```

Am i missing something? Maybe I don't quite get how layzing loading works!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: wow, it attempted to load current slide and 1 adjacent slide. And I have just fixed the problem, please download the latest version. Thanks!

Comment: I redownloaded the library from the github repository. I replaced the jssor.slider.mini.js file, but it is still downloading all the images when i refresh (and clearing the cache). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Any url that I can have a look?

Comment: I sended an email at your @live.com adress